# How can I use component variable in Firebase function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

from this

```
export class firebaseComponent {

public count: any;

ngOnInit() {
   var ref = this.db.database.ref('/approval');
   ref.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function( snapShot ) {
      this.count = snapShot.myValue; // Doesn't work
   }
}
```

I can't use `this.count` because in Firebase function does't know what is `this.count`

How can I use it. I really want to get value from Firebase to show at `{{count}}` in HTML

Comment: `.on('child_added', function( snapShot ) {` should be `.on('child_added', ( snapShot ) => {`

Comment: Thanks you sir  @echonax